# How do I log in to salesforce from angular 7 app?

Tags: angular, authentication, oauth, salesforce

I need to log in to salesforce as a user. So the user will input their username and password to be authenticated. We currently have a pretty bad Electron app that does this by producing a popup window that goes tot he salesforce login page and returns to another salesforce page with a token in the URL. This then gets passed back to the original page in a callback function. However when I use this code in Angular 7 I get the following error

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:4200" from accessing a
>   cross-origin frame.

The code also looks a bit like a hack rather than a correct way to authenticate with salesforce...

Does anyone know of the correct way to do this as my searches only throw up ways to authenticate to use the APIs which are not specific to particular users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rest API or Soap API to connect to salesforce and get your session id base on the user name and password

**if you used REST API:**
Create a connected app:
Use the following steps to create a new connected app.

Use Salesforce to create a new connected app.

1.In Lightning Experience, use the App Manager to create connected apps. From Setup, enter App in the Quick Find box, then select App
   Manager. Click New Connected App.

2.In Salesforce Classic, from Setup, enter Apps in the Quick Find box, then select Apps (under Build | Create). Under Connected Apps,
   click New.

3.Enter the name of your application.

4.Enter the contact email information, as well as any other information appropriate for your application.

5.Select Enable OAuth Settings.

6.Enter a Callback URL. Depending on which OAuth flow you use, this is typically the URL that a user’s browser is redirected to after
   successful authentication. As this URL is used for some OAuth flows
   to pass an access token, the URL must use secure HTTP (HTTPS) or a
   custom URI scheme. Separate multiple callback URLs with line breaks.
   The callback URL field has a limit of 2000 characters, cumulatively.
   If you enter several URLs and they exceed this limit, configure
   another connected app to manage more callback URLs.

7.Add all supported OAuth scopes to Selected OAuth Scopes. These scopes refer to permissions given by the user running the connected
   app.

8.Enter a URL for Info URL. This is where the user can go for more information about your application.

9.Click Save.

10.The Consumer Key is created and displayed, and the Consumer Secret is created (click the link to reveal it).

11.Once you define a connected app, you use the consumer key and consumer secret to authenticate your application. See Creating a
   Connected App in the Salesforce online help for specific steps to
   create a connected app for the type of authentication you need.

in angular create a service that call your standard salesforce rest api for login by using this:

-**Method** : POST

-**Endpoint** : https://services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=
&client_secret=&username=&password=

you will receive then your session id
**Don't use Iframe it will never work**

**Soap**:
Use your wsdl partner
You can generate your functions from the wsdl and use the it for login to get the session id

Regards,

Comment: yes i did this but it rejects the local call from angular?

Comment: @MahmoudTurki have you found solution for this